# GlassFish HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error(JSTL)

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

When I try to run my Web Application using JSP, the GlassFish server returns the follow message:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
root cause

javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.1.0 logs.

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.1.0
```

And I don't knhow what to do. I think the error is connected to [Can't find javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar library in glassfish server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68364265/cant-find-javax-servlet-jsp-jstl-jar-library-in-glassfish-server)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the MySQL JDBC jar file available to Glassfish.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-glassfish-config.html

Comment: But I have already done that still I have the error

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured it out, all I had to do was to set the datasource class name to

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource
```

since I was using MySql connetor J version 8.

Initally I had set the datasource class name to

```
com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MySqlDataSource
```